# VB6 ADO out of memory

Tags: arrays, memory, vb6, ado

Hi using VB6 I am using ADO to load data into an array and I am getting an error. Actually I've seen 2 different runtime errors. 
Runtime Error 7 : Out of Memory 
and 
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

debugger leads to this line.

```
  returnarray = myRecSet.GetRows
```

so my computer is running out of memory and can't load the rows into my array? 
Is there a way to allocate more memory? It's hard to believe so much data is coming through that it can't load this array. 
Based on my calculations I think I am trying to load 1,024,000 records into the array.

any ideas what I should do?

Comment: Open the DB to check that there arent many more rows than you think, but row count is just the start (1 million  rows * rowdatasize).  Do you *need* all the rows all at once?

Comment: checked, it's actually only 888K rows of data. Yes, I need all the output.

Comment: So a cursor won't work fro what you need?

Comment: sorry, I don't know what "a cursor" is. I have a cursor in this text box I am using to reply but that clearly isn't what you are talking about. Please explain.

Comment: You could start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260802(v=vs.60).aspx.  There are plenty of examples out there.  A "forward only" cursor would allow you to process rows sequentially.

Comment: It might help us to help you if you show us what you do with the array when you've loaded it.

Comment: To sum it up without posting a bunch of code: use ADO to pull from Teradata and load into array. Iterate through array elements process a few things and load into a second array with more columns and same number of rows. Then spit 2nd array onto excel sheet. Format a few things.. call it a day.

Comment: hi Jim I don't even need to go backward but because I am loading the total set into the array then using a ubound for loop to process,... wouldn't the cursor not help? maybe I don't understand.

Comment: The recordset/cursor already has the data in it which you can iterate as needed.  Row data will be delivered as the client app needs it.

Comment: that's fantastic, but how do I address elements and or loop through recordset without loading it into an array? Currently I am doing something like For x = 0 to ubound(returnarray )

Comment: You use `RS.MoveNext` method. Arrays require contiguous memory - you don't have enough contiguous memory available.